# Updating Redux State Immutably

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, sheetjs

I am changing the state immutably but this is not working. Basically, I created a function to fetch excel file data. This function works perfectly but when I update the state then the state not updated.

> Any idea or any suggestions share with me

Here is my state:

```
tableData: [],
productsData: []
```

And here is the reducer where the state updated:

```js
case actionTypes.READ_EXCEL:
            var excel1 = [];
            var excel2 = [];
            const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(action.payload);
                fileReader.onload = (e) => {
                    const bufferArray = e.target.result;
                    const wb = { SheetNames:[], Sheets:{} };
                    const ws1 = XLSX.read(bufferArray, {type: "buffer"}).Sheets.Sheet1;
                    const ws2 = XLSX.read(bufferArray, {type: "buffer"}).Sheets.Sheet2;

                    wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet1");
                    wb.Sheets["Sheet1"] = ws1;
                    
                    wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet2");
                    wb.Sheets["Sheet2"] = ws2;

                    const data1 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws1);
                    const data2 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws2);
                    resolve([ data1, data2 ]);
                }
                fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                };
            })
            promise.then((excelData) => {
                excel1 = excelData[0];
                excel2 = excelData[1];
                
            });
            return {
                ...state,
                tableData: excel1,
                productsData: excel2
                }
        default:
    }
    return state; 
}
```

In the UI getting state value and state value not updated:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
  items: state.tableData,     <---
  products: state.productsData    <---
 };
}
```

Comment: You should move your async operations out of your reducer.  Use the reducer to write data to your tree, not to fetch data.  Look into thunks or sagas for handling side effects.

Comment: Correct! reducer should be plain JavaScript function where it should return updated state. It should not contain async function or sideEffects. In UI, you can have dispatch function to perform async operation and then pass data to update the state.

Comment: You can use `redux-thunk` for your async reducer actions, that will fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promises are async the return statements are getting executed first and then the data is loaded into excel1 and excel2.

```js
case actionTypes.READ_EXCEL:
            var excel1 = [];
            var excel2 = [];
            /*Below line will create a promise, which will be executed asynchronously. 
            So the execution will not wait until promise is executed.
            It will go to next line which is Promise.then()*/ 

            const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(action.payload);
                fileReader.onload = (e) => {
                    const bufferArray = e.target.result;
                    const wb = { SheetNames:[], Sheets:{} };
                    const ws1 = XLSX.read(bufferArray, {type: "buffer"}).Sheets.Sheet1;
                    const ws2 = XLSX.read(bufferArray, {type: "buffer"}).Sheets.Sheet2;

                    wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet1");
                    wb.Sheets["Sheet1"] = ws1;
                    
                    wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet2");
                    wb.Sheets["Sheet2"] = ws2;

                    const data1 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws1);
                    const data2 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws2);
                    resolve([ data1, data2 ]);
                }
                fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                };
            })
           /*here as well the we're just attaching a callback to promise to be executed after promise is fulfilled. so execution will attach the specified callback (excelData arrow function) to promise.then(). 
           And then execution will move to next line which is return statement.*/ 
            promise.then((excelData) => {
                excel1 = excelData[0];
                excel2 = excelData[1];
                
            });
             /*Now here, as the promises are async and will be executed after the fileReader reads data, the values of excel1 and excel2 are not updated but only contain the empty array. 
            And hence your state will have empty arrays in it*/
            return {
                ...state,
                tableData: excel1,
                productsData: excel2
                }
        default:
    }
    return state; 
}
```

You can do one thing that write the code for reading the data using fileReader into  one function which will be executed where you currently have placed dispatch statement in your code. And inside the promise.then() you can call dispatch with the loaded data. so your new code might look like this

```
// separate function for reading the data
function readExcel(excelData) {
    return dispatch=>{
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(excelData);
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
            const bufferArray = e.target.result;
            const wb = {
                SheetNames: [],
                Sheets: {}
            };
            const ws1 = XLSX.read(bufferArray, {
                type: "buffer"
            }).Sheets.Sheet1;
            const ws2 = XLSX.read(bufferArray, {
                type: "buffer"
            }).Sheets.Sheet2;

            wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet1");
            wb.Sheets["Sheet1"] = ws1;

            wb.SheetNames.push("Sheet2");
            wb.Sheets["Sheet2"] = ws2;

            const data1 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws1);
            const data2 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws2);
            resolve([data1, data2]);
        }
        fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
            reject(error);
        };
    })
    promise.then((excelData) => {
        excel1 = excelData[0];
        excel2 = excelData[1];
        // Dispatching only after we get the data from fileReader
        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.READ_EXCEL,
            payload: {
                excel1,
                excel2
            }
        })
      });
   }
}

// In reducer function
case actionTypes.READ_EXCEL:
    return {
        ...state,
        tableData: action.payload.excel1,
        productsData: action.payload.excel2
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but what about redux-thunks middleware. How to use these?

Comment: Here is the sample example look for 'export const addTodo'
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/redux-redux-thunk#:~:text=Redux%20Thunk%20is%20a%20middleware,the%20asynchronous%20operations%20have%20completed.

Now in your example, we can write it as 

export const readExcel = (excelFile) => {
  return dispatch => {
    /*Promise and filereader logic*/
promise.then((excelData) => {
        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.READ_EXCEL,
            payload: {
                excelData[0],
                excelData[1]
            }
        })
    })

Comment: According to your suggestion, the separate function readExcel not call in any place

Comment: In your current code, where are you calling dispatch with action type actionTypes.READ_EXCEL?

Comment: Sorry, your answer is great but I am not able implement it. Can you more elaborate on this answer?

Comment: Sure, Are you using redux-thunk ? 
If not then you might need to use it as redux-react can dispatch normal actions, but for asynchronous actions redux-thunk should be installed as well.

Once look into this blog https://medium.com/swlh/handling-asynchronous-actions-with-redux-thunk-86b8d8e0b83e

Comment: I read this blog many things cleared. Only one thing not cleared. The readExcel function in (excelData) parameter  I want to snd file which I have selected and performed all operations in the function. Is this possible or not?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. If you check the blog again, you'll see that they've added mapDispatchToProps in the bottom of the component and attached the action 'fetchingPosts' to the component. Now if you observe there is no parameter to the arrow function  
fetchingPosts: () => { dispatch(fetchingPosts()) }
We can send parameters to it
fetchingPosts: (data) => { dispatch(fetchingPosts(data)) }
And call it in our component as this.props.fetchingPost(data)

Same can be done for our function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222760/discussion-between-muzamil-hussain-and-aadi-git).

Answer (score 1):

The new state does not change because your Promise resolves after the return statement, this happens because of the nature of a Promise, it won't block the execution of your function, I would suggest using some middleware like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for async logic like in your example reading files. Finally, you pass the excel data to your reducer in order to update the store.